# Square root's inequality

Tags: inequality

Could anyone help me solve this inequality? I would be really grateful if you showed how to calculate it with steps. Thank you in advance.

> $\sqrt{x+2} + \sqrt{x-5} \ge 5 - x$

Answer (score 14):

The expression is only defined for $x\geq 5$, however for all $x\geq 5$ the left hand side is positive and the right hand side is non-positive, hence it holds for all $x\geq 5$.